# Can I create a new Activity on the first click of a button and after the first click open the previously created activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onclick, buttonclick

I've been developing a Grade/GPA Calculator Android application during my free time and I'm wondering if there's a way to do the following:

In my *MainActivity* I'm letting the user add as many *Semesters* as they want and the idea is that when a user clicks on, for example, *Fall Semester 2020* the Activity will change to the Activity that will have the *Classes* the user is taking during that specific semester. My question would be, is there a way I can do that? Because I thought of creating a *SemesterActivity*, but the problem with that would be that it will always redirect to the same Activity so it will always have the same content so it doesn't matter if the user clicks on *Summer Semester 2020* or *Fall Semester 2020* it would open the same activity with the same classes that the user had added.

I've been doing some research online about creating an activity on the click of a button, but I've had no luck and I'm not sure if that's really what I should do. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Edit: Maybe this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dzTX.jpg) might help with what I want to do. As you can see, I click on a specific Semester and it redirects to an empty Activity that has a button that lets the user add new courses and that's what I want to do, but I want to do one for each semester

Comment: Did you want to create a new activity after every button click?

Comment: I want to create the same empty Activity on the first click of the button. After the first click I want to open the Activity attached to that button and be able to let the user add the Courses/Classes they're taking for that specific semester. I don't know if I'm explaining myself in the best way, sorry. @SumitSingh

Comment: I would suggest you use fragments instead of multiple activities. Just have the main activity and add a fragment for each option (button). It will make it easy for you to code differently in each fragment for your options.

Comment: I'll look into it. Appreciate your help! @SumitSingh

Comment: an upvote from you will make me feel much better 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You would need to use Extra to pass data to SemesterActivity to tell it what semester to render data accordingly. To do that in MainActivity:

Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SemesterActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("semester","Summer2020");
startActivity(myIntent);

in SemesterActivity, you retrieve the Extra and determine the semester:

Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
String semester= myIntent.getStringExtra("semester");
```

Comment: I'll look into this. Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: In the ```SemesterActivity``` should I put those lines of code on the ```onCreate```? That's what I'm thinking of doing, but I'm not sure if it's what I should do. Thanks! @Don Ha